# Hyperlink alias in confirmation message

Tags: html, google-apps-script, hyperlink, google-forms

Is there a way to put an aliased hyperlink in the confirmation message of Google forms?

I'd like the message to look like "thanks for your answer, please click here" while the word "here" is clickable and directs to a url.

I've tried these while customizing the confirmation message, but they are displayed exactly like the code itself, except for the hyperlink which is clickable:

```
[alias](hyperlink)

<a href=hyperlink>alias</a>

[[hyperlink|alias]]

HYPERLINK(hyperlink, alias)

=HYPERLINK(hyperlink, alias)
```

I've tried wrapping the hyperlink with quotes.

I've found nothing in the Forms Service documentation for [setConfirmationMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setConfirmationMessage(String)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confirmation message only allows the use of plain text.

The Forms Service documentation and the Google Forms help article doesn't mention that the confirmation messages supports HTML or any other kind of markup.

Comment: Booooo! Google should do this :)